# Twitter API with Angularjs and Cordova

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, twitter

I've been searching for a while now and haven't found a clear answer on using Twitters API with angular and cordova. Basically I need to search trending topics but have my own style for the results.

Now the solutions I've found use cordova's inappbrowser to pull up the default twitter widget, but it does not fit with the native feel.

Also, I'm getting mixed answers about needing to authenticate users some how. If I'm search trending tweets, do I need to authenticate the user?

Comment: please share if you got an answer for this